# Encog - EarlyStoppingStrategy with validation set

Tags: java, validation, neural-network, backpropagation, encog

I would like to stop training a network once I see the error calculated from the validation set starts to increase. I'm using a BasicNetwork with RPROP as the training algorithm, and I have the following training iteration:

```
double validationError = 999.999;


    while(!stop){

        train.iteration(); //weights are updated here

        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error : " + train.getError()) ;

        //I'm just comparing to see if the error on the validation set increased or not
        if (network.calculateError(validationSet) < validationError)
            validationError = network.calculateError(validationSet); 

        else
            //once the error increases I stop the training.
            stop = true ;

        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + "Validation Error" + network.calculateError(validationSet));

        epoch++;

    }
        train.finishTraining();
```

Obviously this isn't working because the weights have already been changed before figuring out if I need to stop training or not. Is there anyway I can take a step back and use the old weights?

I also see the `EarlyStoppingStrategy` class which is probably what I need to use by using the `addStrategy()` method. However, I really don't understand why the `EarlyStoppingStrategy` constructor takes both the validation set and the test set. I thought it would only need the validation set and the test set shouldn't be used at all until I test the output of the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encog's EarlyStoppingStrategy class implements an early stopping strategy according to this paper:

Proben1 | A Set of Neural Network Benchmark Problems and Benchmarking Rules

(a full cite is included in the Javadoc)

If you just want to stop as soon as a validation set's error no longer improves you may just want to use the Encog SimpleEarlyStoppingStrategy, found here:

org.encog.ml.train.strategy.end.SimpleEarlyStoppingStrategy

Note, that SimpleEarlyStoppingStrategy requires Encog 3.3.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Really appreciate your time answering some of my questions. I updated my libraries to Encog 3.3 and added the stopping strategy. However, I'm just not very clear on how the SimpleEarlyStoppingStrategy decides that the validation set's error is not improving. Based on the output I have it doesn't seem to have selected the best set of weights for the problem. Maybe I should post this as another question?

Comment: It checks the current error of the validation set every "checkFrequency" iterations.  Once the validation error no longer improves, training stops.